# Cannot run script via crontab

Tags: bash, cron

i want to run a script via crontab, but I get an error message and don't know how to fix it.

It works fine if I run it in the shell.

Code:

```
#$/bin/bash

DIR=/var/log
REC="foo@bar.com foo@bar.de"



TOTALFILES="$(/home/pi/scripts/count-files-dirs $DIR | cut -d' ' -f2)"

#echo "$TOTALFILES"

if (( "$TOTALFILES" > 36 )); then
    echo -e "Subject:$(date +%A' '%d' '%B' '%G) PI-07 var/log status \n\n $(/usr/games/cowsay moh moh moh)\n" | sendmail $REC
else
    true
fi
```

Error:

```
/home/pi/scripts/check-files: 12: /home/pi/scripts/check-files: 48: not found
```

I tried to find the issue, but I don't know where it is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to define the sendmail path. You can find the path with 
    'whereis sendmail'
 almost like you did with cowsay.

Answer (score 2):

The first line in your script should be:

```
#!/bin/bash
```

Comment: Are you sure that's enough to correct the issue ? Aren't cron script executed through `/bin/sh` unless you redefine the `SHELL` variable ?

Comment: my guess is that cron is executing in a shell that does not understand arithmetic expressions

Answer (score 0):

The error indicates something in this file was not found, would need to see the content of this file to be able to tell (or make a guess).

```
/home/pi/scripts/check-files: 48: not found
```